# exim4 using wrong mail server hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, exim

Email no longer works on my Linux box (Debian 6) since our corporate IT group changed the gateway IP address and the hostname of the corporate mail server. I have changed the gateway address on the PC but it is still trying to resolve the name of the old server, which of course fails. Here's a snippet of the output I got when manually sending a test email:

```
--------> smarthost router <--------
local_part=john.doe domain=bigcompany.com
checking domains
bigcompany.com in "@:localhost:coiengrg.foo.com"? no (end of list)
bigcompany.com in "! +local_domains"? yes (end of list)
R: smarthost for john.doe@bigcompany.com
calling smarthost router
smarthost router called for john.doe@bigcompany.com
  domain = bigcompany.com
route_item = * lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com byname
bigcompany.com in "*"? yes (matched "*")
original list of hosts = "lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com" options = byname
expanded list of hosts = "lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com" options = byname
set transport remote_smtp_smarthost
finding IP address for lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com
calling host_find_byname
gethostbyname2(af=inet6) returned 3 (NO_RECOVERY)
gethostbyname2(af=inet) returned 1 (HOST_NOT_FOUND)
no IP address found for host lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com
lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com in dns_again_means_nonexist? no (option unset)
smarthost router: defer for john.doe@bigcompany.com
  message: host lookup for lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com did not complete (DNS timeout?)
john.doe@bigcompany.com cannot be resolved at this time: host lookup for lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com did not complete (DNS timeout?)
```

Where is this outdated mail server hostname coming from, and how can I get the PC to use (or request?) the correct one?

Comment: Which was the old domain name, and what's the new one?

Comment: The domain name was not changed; only the IP address of the gateway, and the hostname of the mail server.

Comment: So you want to figure out where `lisl-xbck-c1-v1.bigcompanyglobal.com` is set so you can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration should be in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`.  You can edit this file directly and reload exim4.  However, the recommended update procedure is to run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and change the host name when prompted.